# Using the message-selector for fetch NON-GROUPED Messages

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq

I need to use an MDB to fetch two kinds of messages of the same queue, one in Groups and the other NOT in groups. 
I can successfully pick up grouped messages using `JMS_IBM_Last_Msg_In_Group=true`, and I now need the second MDB to fetch NON GROUPED messages ONLY but cant seem to find a way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Messages in a group will have a GroupId set. So you can get only those messages whose GroupId is not set. More information in GroupId [here.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr13170_.htm)

Comment: Tnx  Shashi - i have read the documentation but its the message -selector syxtax on the grouID  i need help on here ....

Comment: OK. Does this help? 

MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, "JMSXGroupID='""');

Comment: Hi Shashi - tried the above as follows in the ejb.jar.xml <message-selector>JMSXGroupID IS NULL</message selector> and <message-selector>JMSXGroupID='""'</message selector> but none of them seems to work.

Comment: Hi there, this is strange the code:                                                  MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "JMSXGroupID IS NULL");   works ok but when I use the same selector:JMSXGroupID IS NULL in the ejb-jar.xml descriptor it doesnt seem to have any effect. Can someone pls help on this ? Thanks in advance.